# Would it be possible to make Trophys / Achievements from bitcoin experience

Tags: development, privacy, message-signing, contracts, multi-signature

One Trophy could be: "First output signed"
And many more milestones on the road to the more advanced usages of the network: "First multisign/multispend", "First completed ANYONECANPAY transaction"

Would that be possible?

So the user would sign a message with the address used to do these actions, and send it to a "bitcoin trophy" website. Then parsing of the blockchain would pick out the events that awards a Trophy for that user.

How can anonymity be conserved, so that a user would feel safe to collect more Trophys?

Comment: The message could look like: **This is my address and my username is trophyhunter at example.com, please detect my Achievements.** and then the user would be required to send his signature to the website, it looks like this: `G7OdYRGmPFBiCsvqyUCQlYUAwdrTG56khvNbZ7TxHAUMmqJU6TxPJdO9CPh5HZOtKnDRr/dzSnWVuLQ9cxwsh1I=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that could be done, if you use Tor to connect to the website and if you don't spend the coins from those addresses at places where your identity could be tracked (i.e. tumble them first).

Comment: What about if the website running on Tor got hacked, in what way could the users addresses be protected? Lets say the hacker was able to brute force the password for that particular user.

Comment: Well that's no problem as long as your identity can't get linked to that particular adress. So if you want to sent those coins to for example Mt. Gox, where your identity is known, you should [tumble](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mixing_service) your coins first.

Comment: In this use case, a lot of addresses is tracked for Achievements. Lets assume the user is really paranoid but at the same time wants to detect all his combined Trophys